# batter way to detact ajax call in php

Tags: php, angularjs, ajax

I am using angular and PHP as front end & back end and now i want to detect if some php file is call using Ajax request,

if angular i am doing, this

```
app.controller('LoginController',function($scope,$http){
$scope.loginuser = function() {
    console.log($scope.username+" "+$scope.userpwd);
    $http.post("user/login")
    .success(function (data, status, headers) {
        console.log(data);
        //$scope.nowplaying=data;
    }).error(function (data, status, header) {
        //code to handel error
    });
}

});
```

i so many thing to detect Ajax call like,

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest')) {
// this is ajax request, do something
}
```

but i don't know why this is not working form me, as i can't see `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` when i print `$_SERVER` array.

this is output i am getting,

[image: ARRAY]

so can someone give me hint or show me way to detect ajax in php

PS: i am attaching image to show i ma not getting `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` in responce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default angular not send 'X-Requested-With' for use 'X-Requested-With' you need to configure $httpProvider

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

Or check at php that`s 'Content-Type' is 'application/json'

Comment: perfect answer.

Answer (score 0):

print all the values  $_SERVER variable and check if HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH exists or not.

Some SERVER variables are browser/agent dependent

Comment: output in image is result of print_r($_SERVER)

Answer (score 0):

You can detect it with the help of `$_SERVER` variables

use print_r($_SERVER) to see it clearly, when you request page using ajax you can see `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` parameter under `$_SERVER` variable.

```
<?php
     echo '<pre>';
     print_r($_SERVER);
?>
```

> [HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH] => XMLHttpRequest

if you request normal page then `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` parameter wouldn't available so you can check with below code either it's ajax request or normal request.

```
if ( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && 
     $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest') {
    echo 'Ajax call';
} else {
    echo 'Normal Call';
}
```

Comment: output in image is result of print_r($_SERVER)

Comment: Yes but i told use it with <pre> option you can find it easily, my main point is to cover $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] option, Thank you